# OAuth2 on Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

OAuth1 has been [officially deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto) by Google on April 20, 2012, but the Google Apps Marketplace documentation states that Marketplace apps have to use OAuth1 2 legged authentication. I would much prefer to use an OAuth2 Service Account for my application. Is there some way to assign a marketplace-approved service account for Marketplace applications ?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 with Marketplace Apps is not yet supported. See:

https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v1/marketplace#oauth2